# How can I fix a Selenium that won't connect on Amazon EC2?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, selenium, docker, laradock

In case local environment, it works fine connect to wd / hub with browser, but does't connect in case my server in Amazon EC2.

I'm opened 4444 port on EC2 and my Laradock container for Selenium used 4444 port.

But it doesn't connect to wd/hub with browser in case server on Amazon Web Service.

Why is this?

My Docker container list:

[image: my Docker container list]

And Amazon port stats:

[image: and Amazon port stats]

Comment: Are those network security rules inbound and not outbound?

Comment: i'm edit inbound rules. i don't edit outbound Anything

Comment: Can you try opening a connection to Selenium Server on your EC2 instance itself? Perhaps it is not starting up correctly. It would be worth adding your exact connection error to your question too.